# How to troubleshoot postfix-policyd-spf-python?

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, spf

I've followed several tutorials on how to configure SPF for postfix and I can't make it work. I have testing environment with ubuntu 14 lts, postfix 3.1 ,dovecot and BIND9 setup in virtualbox on local network. This is my postfix configuration:

main.cf

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/smtpd.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/smtpd.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1


# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination check_policy_service
myhostname = example.loc
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, example.loc, ubuntu, localhost.localdomain, localhost
#relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 192.168.20.0/24 192.168.3.0/24
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all

smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes

#SPF
policy-spf_time_limit = 3600s
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination,check_policy_service unix:private/policy-spf
```

master.cf

```
smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
submission inet n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
smtps     inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
pickup    unix  n       -       y       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       y       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       y       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       y       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
showq     unix  n       -       y       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       y       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       y       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       y       -       1       scache
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -   n   n   -   2   pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}

#SPF 
policy-spf  unix  -       n       n       -       -       spawn
     user=nobody argv=/usr/bin/policyd-spf
```

policyd-spf.conf

```
debugLevel = 1 
defaultSeedOnly = 1

HELO_reject = False 
#SPF_Not_Pass
Mail_From_reject = Fail

PermError_reject = False
TempError_Defer = False

skip_addresses = 127.0.0.0/8,::ffff:127.0.0.0/104,::1
```

There are no logs in /var/log/mail.log regarding SPF checks and no headers in emails. How to find out spf policy deamon is working at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In local environment, using 2 servers at 192.168.3.0 I had to change smtpd_recipient_restrictions to:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,reject_unauth_destination,check_policy_service unix:private/policy-spf
```

omitting (permit_mynetworks) parameter. Now i can see SPF headers in emails and logs.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you don't have the correct version of python i.e. python3 needed for the policyd-spf python code to run. The easiest way is to install python3 (if you don't have it) and directly point to it in `master.cf` as shown below.

```
  user=nobody argv=/usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/policyd-spf
```

Other than that, everything looks correct to me.

Once you get it to work, you should see something similar to these below in your `mail.log` assuming a mail sender client failing your policy.

```
Dec  6 22:39:06 gorilla policyd-spf[14506]: 550 5.7.23 Message rejected due to: SPF fail - not authorized. Please see http://www.openspf.net/Why?s=helo;id=hrs.com;ip=183.128.34.50;r=<UNKNOWN>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! I have python 3 installed and pointed argv to it as you suggested. Unfortunately this is not it. Still nothing in mail.log and message headers...

Comment: What makes you think it is not working? Are you sure external mail clients are hitting your server and violate your SPF policy? You have debugLevel=1 which means, logs will contain only errors and failures. I would change it to 3 and see if you get any logs in mail.log. Also, I would recommend setting TestOnly = 0 or defaultSeedOnly=0 for testing & debugging.

Comment: I tried different debug levels, the issue was in local network environment. I finally managed to resolve this. Thank you for your help.